# Integer partitions into restricted parts

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, analytic-number-theory, partitions, enumerative-combinatorics

Given a linear diophantine equation $$x_1+\dots+x_n=m\leq nn'$$ how many solutions does it have with each $x_i\in[0,n']\cap\mathbb Z$? Looking for asymptotics that parametrizes well with both $n$ and $n'$ over different ranges for both situations

1. $x_1\leq\dots\leq x_n$ and
2. unordered.

Comment: Is $m$ a parameter of the problem, or can it take any value within the constraints?

Comment: Supposing they satisfy the conditions, are (2,1,1) and (1,2,1) both counted as solutions? 
 If so, this is a question about integer compositions rather than partitions.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay $m$ is any value within the constraints.

Comment: @BrianHopkins Yes it would be nice to know for both scenarios. When $x_i\leq x_{i+1}$ is forced (partitions) and not forced (compositions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $m$ is a dummy variable (*i.e.* a bound variable) and $n,n'$ are "real" variables (*i.e.* they are free) perhaps we should rewrite the problem accordingly as
$``$compute the following
$$ f(y,z) = \#\left\lbrace  (x_1,... , x_y )\mid  x_1 + ... + x_y = m,\  x_i \in \mathbb{N},\  m \leq yz ,\  i < j \implies x_i \leq x_j \right\rbrace."$$
We can let $f'$ be the number if we omit the condition $i < j \implies x_i \leq x_j$ (*i.e.* $f$ corresponds to partitions and $f'$ corresponds to compositions). Intuition tells us that $f$ will likely have a closed form solution and $f'$ will probably only have solution expressible by generating functions (which are perfect for asymptotics). Let us confirm our intuitions:

> **Compositions (*i.e.* $f'$)**

It is straightforward to see that if we let
$$g(y,m) = \#\left\lbrace (x_1,..., x_y ) \mid  x_1 + ... + x_y = m, \  x_i \in \mathbb{N}\right\rbrace,$$
then we have the identity
$$f'(y,z) = \sum_{m=0}^{yz}g(y,m).$$
It is well known, [see the famous stars and bars method in feller's introduction to probability theory](https://g.co/kgs/jbxxTD), that
$$g(y,m)= \binom{y+m-1}{m},$$

> so that  $$f'(y,z) = \sum_{m=0}^{yz}\binom{y+m-1}{m}= 
> \binom{yz+y}{yz},$$
> (or, using your notation, $f'(n,n')=\binom{nn'+n}{nn'}$)

where the last identity can be derived as a consequence of [Chu Shih-Chieh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zhu_Shijie)'s identity, see example 2.5.1 of [Chuan-Chong & Khee-Meng's text on combinatorics](https://g.co/kgs/PZxPtA). I also strongly recommend taking a peek at [Flajolet & Sedgewick's text on analytic combinatorics](https://g.co/kgs/mtSh6P) for asymptotics and the more abstract [symbolic method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_method_(combinatorics))/[species](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_species) style which is necessary for the more difficult analysis of $f$.

> **Partitions (*i.e.* $f$)**

It is straightforward to see that if we let
$$g(y,m) = \#\left\lbrace  (x_1,... , x_y ) \mid x_1 + ... + x_y = m, \  x_i \in \mathbb{N}, \  i < j \implies x_i \leq x_j\right\rbrace,$$
then we have the identity
$$f(y,z) = \sum_{m=0}^{yz}g(y,m).$$

It is well known that if we define the generating function $\mathcal{G}_y$ as
$$\mathcal{G}_y(x) = \sum_{m \in \mathbb{N}} g(y,m) x^m,$$
then we have that
$$\mathcal{G}_y(x) = \prod_{k=1}^{y}\frac{1}{1-x^k},$$
see [Flajolet & Sedgewick's text on analytic combinatorics](https://g.co/kgs/mtSh6P) or [Andrews elementary text on partitions](https://g.co/kgs/dWf28q). One way to see this is to notice the following famous theorem attributed to Euler

> The number of partitions of a number $n$ into at most $l$ parts is equal to the number of partitions of a number $n$ into parts all bounded by $l$

and the result follows by elementary generating function magic. Finally, theorem 5.1.1 of [Chuan-Chong & Khee-Meng's text on combinatorics](https://g.co/kgs/PZxPtA) states that
$$\mathcal{A}(x) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} a_n x^n \implies \frac{1}{1-x}\mathcal{A}(x) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \left(\sum_{k \leq n} a_k \right) x^n;
$$
therefore, if we define the generating function $\mathcal{F}_y$ as
$$\mathcal{F}_{y}(x) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} f(y,n) x^n,$$

> then we have that $$\mathcal{F}_{y}(x) = \frac{1}{1-x}\mathcal{G}_y(x)
>  =  \frac{1}{1-x}\prod_{k=1}^{y}\frac{1}{1-x^k}. $$

More explicitly we have that
$$f(y,z) = [x^{yz}] \mathcal{F}_{y}(x) =[x^{yz}] \left(\frac{1}{1-x}\prod_{k=1}^{y}\frac{1}{1-x^k}\right)$$
where the operator $[x^{k}] $ is defined as follows:
$$\mathcal{A}(x) = a_0+a_1x+ ... +a_nx^n+ ... \implies [x^{k}]\mathcal{A}(x) = a_k.$$ For the asymptotics please consult [Flajolet & Sedgewick's text on analytic combinatorics](https://g.co/kgs/mtSh6P) where you will find a wealth of information and techniques for extracting the asymptoics of the coefficients of $\mathcal{F}_{y}(x) $.

Comment: Is there a clean asymptotic expression for $f$ just as $f'$ does?

Comment: So $f′(n,n′)$ is only exponential in $n$ because  $\binom{nn′+n}{nn′}\approx(1+\frac1{n′})^{nn′}\rightarrow e^n$? That is surprising isn't it?

Comment: I think it is $e^{n+nn'}$. I think I made a mistake.

Comment: I doubt there is a nice expression for $f$ since partitions tend to not have nice expressions in general but there is a lot of literature written about them. The most famous asymptotic formula known for the partition function is $p(n) \sim \frac{1}{4n\sqrt{3}}\exp\left(\pi \sqrt{\frac{2n}{3}}\right) $ which is due to Hardy and Ramanujan, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_function_(number_theory). Chapter 7 of https://g.co/kgs/pgs3uM also has a lot of material on partitions, mostly algebraic. The definitive text is probably Andrews "the theory of partitions" https://g.co/kgs/HPVXS4

Comment: By nice expression I was thinking a first order asymptotic.

Comment: Also I am wondering what happens if we constraint the difference between maximum and minimum terms? https://mathoverflow.net/questions/365176/integer-partitions-and-compositions-into-restricted-parts-with-a-difference-cond

Comment: I believe this is discussed in I.16 of ch. 1 sec. 3 of analytic combinatorics by Flajolet and Sedgewick *which you can download for free, legally, off of one of the authors' websites here* https://ac.cs.princeton.edu/home/ (sadly the other author passed away recently). Of course, you have to perform some simple manipulations to make it work; perhaps subtracting the minimum from all of the parts to transform it into the case $\min_i x_i' =0$.